# Swagger documentation for Remix loaders and actions

Tags: swagger, remix.run

We've a requirement to document what all APIs are being exposed via our Remix app. Is there a way to generate swagger documentation for Remix loaders and actions (for example POST, DELETE form actions)?

Comment: Based on my research - There is a library for NextJS-Swagger integration - https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-swagger-doc. I tried looking similar for Remix but couldn't find one.